# Why does ray for trigonometric functions not need to be cut?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is for complex variables, I understand that ray of log Z

needs to be cut starting from the origin (since log 0 does not exist)

and give a domain for the theta values,

so we can have one to one mapping. However, trigonometric functions have

same properties as log except its existence at z = 0 but

sine and cosines not need to be cut and they do not map one to one since

the function oscillates same value infinitely. In fact, I am not even sure why these

are considered to be a function. Can someone please clarify me these confusions for me?

Comment: By the phrase "trigonometric functions have same properties as log except..." it appears be that you are thinking that the complex trigonometric functions are $\sin(\arg(z))$, $\cos(\arg(z))$. **They are not**.

Answer (score 4):

> However, trigonometric functions have same properties as log except its existence at $z = 0$.

Utterly false!
$$\log z=\log|z|+i\arg z$$
and is impossible to define an $\arg$ function continuous in $\Bbb C-\{0\}$.
But trigonometric functions can be defined using only the exponential.

Comment: Sorry, yes I stated my claim in a wrong way. Could you help me clarify my question?

Comment: @MathMA, start explaining what means "trigonometric functions have same properties as log". About "I am not even sure why these are considered to be a function", a function can have the same *value* in distinct *points*. Also, I suspect that you are mixing and confusing the real case and the complex case.

Comment: Stupid of me. I was confused with one to one mapping and definition of function. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

$\sin, \cos, \exp\;$ are periodic function. Therefore $\ln$ as  the inverse of $\exp$ is a function only in a domain which is part of the complex plane, or kind of a multi-valued function if defined on the whole complex plane. Because $\exp(z)\ne 0\;$ you cannot define $\ln(0)$. Analogous to $\ln$ would be the inverse trigonometric 'functions' $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ which also have branch cuts.